# Sum two columns of a numpy array and add it as a third column of the array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have following numpy array

`X = np.random.random_integers(100000000,size=(100000000,2))`

now I want to dd both the columns of the array to generate the third column of the array. I am trying `X[3] = X[0]+X[1]` but its shape is `(2,)`.

Example final array :

```
10    5    15
15    6    21
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) with the `sum` along the last axis. An additional axis must be added to the result of `X.sum(1)`, as all arrays to be concatenated must have the same number of dimensions. This can be done either with `None`/`np.newaxis`:

```
np.concatenate([X, X.sum(1)[:,None]], -1)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `[:,None]`

Comment: It adds an axis to `X.sum(1)`, as all arrays to concatenate must have the same number of dimensions @salman

Comment: @SalmanArshad you can also use `keepdims=True` in `sum`, which removes the need for the extra broadcast